# How do I find out he layer of a collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am trying to find out the layer of a collider so when a certain enemy comes along I am categorizing them in layers. At the moment I am adding a enemy which has a certain effect on the player. That's not my problem though, my problem is I don't know how to detect the layer from a collider. Here is my code at the momem

```
public LayerMask layer;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(Collider2D.)
}
```

Comment: Usually you limit the collidable layers by [configuring the collision system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html), 
A) making it unnecessary to check layers in collision handlers
B) increasing the collision system's performance.

Comment: By using `collision.gameObject.layer` ...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the `Collision2D` object has a number of properties for you to check against. By checking the `gameObject` property, you can find out what layer the 'other' object is on.

So, if your case, you could do something like this to make checking against layers a little easier:

```
    // Grab the integer values, for layers associated with these three enemies.
    int enemy1, enemy2, enemy3;

    private void Awake ( )
    {
        enemy1 = LayerMask.NameToLayer ( "EnemyLayer1" );
        enemy2 = LayerMask.NameToLayer ( "EnemyLayer2" );
        enemy3 = LayerMask.NameToLayer ( "EnemyLayer3" );
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D collision )
    {
        var layerMask = collision.gameObject.layer;
        if ( layerMask == enemy1 )
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if ( layerMask == enemy2 )
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if ( layerMask == enemy3 )
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Now that I've answered your question though, you probably DON'T want to check your enemies by the layer they're on. While you can certainly do this, it's generally considered inappropriate. This is what the GameObject Tag is for. You have a lot more tags, and you're not polluting the physics scenes with extra layers. Your physics layer mask would generally include a "Enemy" layer, and then you would be specific my checking a Tag at that point.

For example:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D collision )
    {
        if ( collision.CompareTag ( "Enemy1" ) )
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if ( collision.CompareTag ( "Enemy2" ) )
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if ( collision.CompareTag ( "Enemy3" ) )
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

[Here's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) the Unity docs for the LayerMask struct.

Answer (score 0):

The collider itself doesn't have a layer property. However, the gameObject to which it is attached has one.

So you should be able to write:

```
if (collider2D.gameObject.layer == 3)
```

---

On Collider2D, you also have the function `IsTouchingLayers` which could be useful with what you want to achieve.

It takes a `LayerMask` and returns a `bool`. See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouchingLayers.html.)

N.B.: note that I write `collider2D` here (the instance), not `Collider2D` (the type/class)! That's maybe why you didn't find anything in the autocompletion of your editor.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're using `OnTriggerEnter()` to catch the collision.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (((1 << collider.gameObject.layer) & MyLayerMask) != 0)
    {
        // DO YOUR STUFF
    }
}
```

this `if (((1 << collider.gameObject.layer) & MyLayerMask) != 0)` tells that if the `collider.gameObject.layer` is in the `MyLayerMask`, then execute the code inside the if statement.